# How to make a button with image inside?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to make a buttons that looks like:

[image]

I tried this:

css:

```
button {
   color: #900;
   border: 1px solid #900;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
 }

 button img {
   margin-right: 5px;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

html:

```
<button class="btnExample" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <img src="./images/img04.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt=""/>Submit</button>
```

And result:

[image]

Why image so small(18*18px)? How to make image bigger?

Comment: You given width and height to image.
<img src="./images/img04.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt=""/>

Comment: @ketan Without width and height i got same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this to increase size

```
<img src="./images/img04.jpg" width="28" height="28" alt=""/>Submit</button>
```

to change size change `width=" "` and for `height=" "`

```css
button {
   color: #900;
   border: 1px solid #900;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
 }

 button img {
   margin-right: 5px;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<button class="btnExample" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <img src="http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-kuba-arrow-button-set-clip-art_117492_Kuba_Arrow_Button_Set_clip_art_hight.png" width="58" height="58" alt=""/>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is as big as you make it. From your comments, it seems that the actual size of the image is 18 by 18 pixels. I would be possible to stretch it by setting larger values for the `width` and `height` attributes or by setting the `width` and `height` properties to suitable values in CSS. However, scaling upwards may produce graphically poor results for raster images like jpeg images.

It is therefore better to use a graphics program to create the image in the desired size and change the `width` and `height` attributes to match the new size.